# Symfony 1.4: Find records with no related values

Tags: doctrine, many-to-many, symfony-1.4, relation

I have two tables with related with a many-to-many relationship.  I am trying to find all of the rows that have no related values.  Here's an example:

```
Table 1:  Categories
Table 2:  CategoryItems
Table 3:  Items
```

I am trying to find all of the items that have no categories associated.

If I were writing this in straight SQL, this is what I would do:

```
SELECT *
FROM Items
WHERE Items.item_id not in (SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM category_items)
```

This seems like a fairly straightforward requirement, but I can't figure out how to get Doctrine to do this.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a query like this `SELECT * FROM items left join category_items on ... where cateogry_items.id is null`. In Doctrine that means something like:

```
ItemsTable::getInstance()->createQuery('Items')
  ->leftJoin('Items.CategoryItems CategoryItems')
  ->where('CategoryItems.id IS NULL')
  ->execute()
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm still getting used to Doctrine syntax.  Usually the many-many translation table isn't referenced in a query, but that's exactly what's needed here.

I appreciate the help!